# CodeIgniter, form helper - Adding classes to the elements

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

So i created a form with the CodeIgniter Form helper. I'm trying to give some form elements a class, but something strange happens. I do it like this:

```
echo form_input('title', $this->input->post('title'), 'class="titleInput"');
```

When i inspect the element it actually shows the class is there:

[image]

but it doesn't take any of the property's given in the CSS file. Also when i do something ugly like:

```
echo form_input('title', $this->input->post('title'), style="height=30px");
```

When i inspect the element i get this:

[image]

But it doesn't actually do anything with the styling given.

Hopefully someone can give me a hand here!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$data = array(
          'name'        => 'title',
          'value'          => $this->input->post('title'),
          'class'       => 'titleInput',
          'style'       => 'height:30px'
        );

echo form_input($data);
```

[reference](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Comment: Thx! I've read the docs as well, but thought my approach was going to work aswell, since i actually saw the classes and styling while inspecting the element. On a side note, you should edit and add a comma after the `value` and remove the one behind `style` :) Thx for your help mate!

Comment: How would you add 'disabled' to the above?  There is no identifier, just 'disabled'